# Using Creative Sound Blaster on Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio

I just got a Creative Sound Blaster for playing audio wirelessly. I connected it to a virtual version of Ubuntu desktop and just had to go into the sound settings and switch it to the USB and the device worked. Now I am trying to get it to work on Ubuntu Server 10.04. I plugged it in and restarted the computer, but when I go to /dev I don't see it listed (unless I'm missing it somehow). Does anyone know how to get the Sound Blaster to work on Ubuntu Server?

(I haven't gotten any audio to play out of the server, so if you wanted to include that, I wouldn't mind. However, I feel confident that google will hold the answer to that question...the main question is the Sound Blaster).

Comment: Probably "Server" version does not have kernel module prepacked or enabled. Try updating the kernel `apt-cache search kernel`

Comment: I'm still stuck on how OP is playing audio "wirelessly" ... playing audio through a network to a wireless device doesn't involve a sound card in any way.  Wireless speakers... still no sound card.  My brain hurts!    And the card should show up under `/dev/dsp*` and others, and be listed in the files within `/proc/asound`